# ionic Splash Screen not displayed and having a white screen in ionic view

Tags: android, cordova, ionic-framework, ionic2, splash-screen

I am getting `404 /screen` and `404 /apidata.json` in terminal *(attached the screenshot below)* when running it via `cordova run browser`. There is no splash screen displayed. It goes directly to the root page (It is working without displaying the splash screen). And I am testing this app on **ionic view** as well. It is displaying only a white screen in the old android devices (in ionic view). But the app is working fine **without the splash screen**  on the updated android devices (Android 5.0 - with ionic view). As I am new to ionic, I do not know what causes this.

Note: I have replaced the splash.png in resources folder. And after that I've ran `ionic cordova resources`. It has added different variations (png files) derived from the splash.png in the resources folder to the ./resources/android/splash folder. (It is fine. But the app is not displaying it when starts.)

Here are some  more information on my setup.

---

Other Information-

```
PS E:\Sen Files\dev\99eeeeeeeeeeeex\Mobile app\to test\Amila ayyas git\endCusApp> npm list -g --depth=0
C:\Users\Senura\AppData\Roaming\npm
+-- babel@6.23.0
+-- babel-cli@6.24.1
+-- cordova@7.0.1
+-- ionic@3.5.0
`-- nodemon@1.11.0




PS E:\Sen Files\dev\99eeeeeeeeeeeex\Mobile app\to test\Amila ayyas git\endCusApp> cordova platform ls
Installed platforms:
  android 4.0.0
  browser 4.1.0
Available platforms:
  blackberry10 ~3.8.0 (deprecated)
  webos ~3.7.0
  windows ~5.0.0
```

[image]

[image: Cordova run info]

[image]

[image]

### [More screenshots](https://1drv.ms/f/s!Ao3_PEzak8vNkTJ_InYHGJZS26Tg) << Link

Hope you will look in to this. And Thank you for reading this. Please tell me what is causing this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The splash screen is a native feature of mobile devices. The browser aswell as Ionic View are only previews for your design. Cordova plugins and native features will only work in simulators like Android Studio or in the final app build (as .apk for example).

Comment: Thanks. I have built an apk file and simulated that using an android emulator. Now it's showing the splash screen. But after that white screen appears and nothing displayed.

error: `07-23 07:24:47.758 1215-1215/io.ionic.starter E/Web Console: Uncaught SyntaxError: Use of future reserved word in strict mode at file:///android_asset/www/build/main.js:40`

Maybe this is not regarding to the above question.

Comment: Which android version do you use on the emulator?

Comment: Android ver. 5.0.0

Comment: I have made a question  regarding this > https://stackoverflow.com/q/45262952/7328702