# ionic android white screen after showing the splash screen

Tags: android, cordova, ionic-framework, ionic2, genymotion

I have built an apk file using  `ionic cordova build android`. And I have opened that app using Genymotion emulator. When I opened the app, it starts and displays the splash screen. After that a white screen appears forever (I can close the app. But when I start that again, same thing happens).

I have captured the error in the android studio console.

Here they are,

[image: Error with White Screen]

And then I have opened the main.js file in that apk. In line 40, I have found this code.

[image: Error source -main.js line 40]

Then I browsed the scanner.ts in pages (./pages/scanner/scanner.ts) folder.
I did not find anything wrong. It works when I run that using `cordova run browser`.

**scanner.ts**
[image: scanner.ts file content]

Here are some more information on my setup:

```
npm list -g --depth=0
+-- babel@6.23.0
+-- babel-cli@6.24.1
+-- cordova@7.0.1
+-- ionic@3.5.0
-- nodemon@1.11.0

Installed platforms:
  android 4.0.0
  browser 4.1.0
Available platforms:
  blackberry10 ~3.8.0 (deprecated)
  webos ~3.7.0
  windows ~5.0.0
```

Thanks for reading this post. If you know what causes this. Or how to resolve this issue,  Please let me know.

Comment: Can you share your `tsconfig.json`, please?

Comment: `{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "declaration": false,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "lib": [
      "dom",
      "es2015"
    ],
    "module": "es2015",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "target": "es6"
  },
  "include": [
    "src/**/*.ts"
  ],
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules"
  ],
  "compileOnSave": false,
  "atom": {
    "rewriteTsconfig": false
  }
}`

Comment: Ok, can you change the `"target"` from `"es6"` to `"es5"` and try it again?

Comment: Hooray...! After the splash screen, it loads the webcam to scan the bar-code. But after getting that, I'm getting a white screen as before. 
here's the error displayed in the android studio : 
`07-23 09:28:21.883 1024-1024/io.ionic.starter E/Web Console: ERROR at file:///android_asset/www/build/vendor.js:1591`

Comment: Can you share the relevant lines of code?

Comment: [IMG]http://i67.tinypic.com/t5lroo.jpg[/IMG]
Here's the screenshot of the vender.js file contents (line 1591)

Comment: @StephanStrate
1591th line comes to > `console.error.apply(console, values);`

Where the whole code block is > 
`function defaultErrorLogger(console) {
    var values = [];
    for (var _i = 1; _i < arguments.length; _i++) {
        values[_i - 1] = arguments[_i];
    }
    console.error.apply(console, values);
}`

Comment: Unfortunately this is not really helpful. This error is related to the code you have written, I guess. That it crashes after it did something.

Comment: @StephanStrate Thanks for your response. You have partially resolved my problem. At least now my scanner is working. Thanks. I'll dig more into code and try to solve that. Thanks !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changing the target value in the `tsconfig.json` from `es6` to `es5` has worked.

Eg. `"target": "es6"` >>> `"target": "es5"`

Note: This problem will not automatically happen to the project unless you declare that explicitly.

Answer (score 4):

The best of clarity is to find error، error on the emulator.

Debug Ionic Android Application On Mobile Devices or Emulators.

Inspect elements and network monitor, the same way you do with websites. Use chrome dev tools, write chrome://inspect/#devices in chrome address bar and hit enter. It will open the following page in your browser, showing all devices and hybrid applications running on it.

[image]

Now clicking on **inspect** will open the same inspection window like web page. See the following image for visual understanding.
[image]

[For more info](https://www.codeproject.com/Tips/1030830/Debug-Ionic-Android-Application-On-Mobile-Devices)

Answer (score 0):

You just need to add a new virtual device with the exact API version of your Android SDK and the white screen will go.